# $compile not working in unit test

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, karma-runner

I'm new to angular and am trying to get a handle on testing but have been stumped for a while on a seemingly stupid issue, and perhaps it is a lack of understanding for $compile. I have boiled my unit test code down to the following:

```
it('should create a table', inject(['$compile', '$rootScope', function ($compile, $rootScope) {
    var element;
    var scope = $rootScope.$new();
    scope.list = [{name: 'tst'},{name:'sae'},{name:'dkos'}]
    element = angular.element('<ul><li ng-repeat="p in list">{{p.name}}</li></ul>');
    element = $compile(element)(scope);
    expect(element.find('li').length).to.equal(3);
}]));
```

When I run karma I receive the following failure:

```
$ grunt karma:unit
Running "karma:unit" (karma) task
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.10.10 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
INFO [Chrome 33.0.1750 (Mac OS X 10.9.2)]: Connected on socket 6K3QkOOLMEYRkZco3rY3
Chrome 33.0.1750 (Mac OS X 10.9.2) Directive: ngTabled should create a table FAILED
    AssertionError: expected 0 to equal 3
        at Context.<anonymous> (/Users/andyperlitch/js/ng-tabled/test/spec/directives/ng-tabled.js:22:44)
        at Object.invoke (/Users/andyperlitch/js/ng-tabled/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3697:17)
        at Context.workFn (/Users/andyperlitch/js/ng-tabled/app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2102:20)
        at callFn (/Users/andyperlitch/js/ng-tabled/node_modules/mocha/mocha.js:4338:21)
        at Test.Runnable.run (/Users/andyperlitch/js/ng-tabled/node_modules/mocha/mocha.js:4331:7)
        at Runner.runTest (/Users/andyperlitch/js/ng-tabled/node_modules/mocha/mocha.js:4728:10)
        at /Users/andyperlitch/js/ng-tabled/node_modules/mocha/mocha.js:4806:12
        at next (/Users/andyperlitch/js/ng-tabled/node_modules/mocha/mocha.js:4653:14)
        at /Users/andyperlitch/js/ng-tabled/node_modules/mocha/mocha.js:4663:7
        at next (/Users/andyperlitch/js/ng-tabled/node_modules/mocha/mocha.js:4601:23)
    Error: Declaration Location
        at window.inject.angular.mock.inject (/Users/andyperlitch/js/ng-tabled/app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2087:25)
        at Suite.<anonymous> (/Users/andyperlitch/js/ng-tabled/test/spec/directives/ng-tabled.js:16:31)
        at context.describe.context.context (/Users/andyperlitch/js/ng-tabled/node_modules/mocha/mocha.js:955:10)
        at /Users/andyperlitch/js/ng-tabled/test/spec/directives/ng-tabled.js:3:1
Chrome 33.0.1750 (Mac OS X 10.9.2): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.21 secs / 0.029 secs)
Warning: Task "karma:unit" failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.


Execution Time (2014-03-31 06:41:05 UTC)
karma:unit  2.5s  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 100%
Total 2.5s
```

I'm tearing my hair out over this, so any help would be great! I'd be happy to provide more details if necessary.

Andy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like it needs a call to `scope.$digest()` after the call to `$compile()` in order for the the `ng-repeat` to run over the list. So your test can be like:

```
it('should create a table', inject(['$compile', '$rootScope', function ($compile, $rootScope) {
  var element;
  var scope = $rootScope.$new();
  scope.list = [{name: 'tst'},{name:'sae'},{name:'dkos'}]
  element = angular.element('<ul><li ng-repeat="p in list">{{p.name}}</li></ul>');
  element = $compile(element)(scope);
  scope.$digest();
  expect(element.find('li').length).toEqual(3);
}]));
```

This can be seen in-action at http://plnkr.co/edit/ypDZeSPMggknqsuiETh8?p=preview